# Implement `--https-redirect` when using `prpl-server` as express framework

Tags: express, polymer, polymer-3.x

In `prpl-server`'s `README`, it says that you can use the `--https-redirect` flag in order to redirect any `http` requests to `https`. I was wondering how to do something similar when using it as an express framework?